# Segmentation fault (core dumped) due to fgets - I think

Tags: c

but I keep getting this error when I run this program. I think it's because of the fgets function. I tried initializing the input variable to NULL to see if that'll help, but it didn't. I also have a hunch that I might need to malloc to solve the problem. But your help is highly appreciated.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* input = NULL;

    // ensure one and only one command line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [name of document]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // open a new document for writing
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");

    // check for successful open
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not create %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    // get text from user and save to file
    while(true)
    {
        // get text from user
        printf("Enter a new line of text (or \"quit\"):\n");
        fgets(input, 50, stdin);

        // if user wants to quit
        if (input != NULL && strcmp(input, "quit") == 0)
        {
            free(input);
            break;
        }
        // if user wants to enter text
        else if (input != NULL)
        {
            fputs(input, fp);
            fputs("\n", fp);
            printf("CHA-CHING!\n\n");
            free(input);
        }
    }

    // close the file and end successfuly
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only use `free` on memory that you have allocated with `malloc` and friends. You have not allocated any memory here.

Comment: @DavidBowling: `free` is legal here actually, despite the lack of `malloc`, because `NULL` can be `free`-ed safely, but it's not very useful.

Comment: Check the [manual for how `fgets(3)` works](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). Passing a NULL pointer to `fgets(3)` is really wrong and unexpected. As a general recommendation for your future endeavours: *don't ever just use some function without fist reading its documentation to learn how it works.*

Comment: @ShadowRanger this may sound pedantic, but while this code is "legal", in the sense that it won't invoke UB, it isn't "legal", in the sense that it's, well, wrong. There was no intention from the author to allocate any memory, so there shouldn't be any `free()`. It just didn't cause problems because, maybe for sheer luck, the author initialized the pointer to `NULL`, and that statement never executed (probably optimized away, actually). As a general rule, the programmer must keep good track of their pointers, not rely on them being NULL.

Comment: (I wanted to edit the above comment, but I can't; it's past 5 minutes). I wanted to strike out the part where I said "and that statement never executed (probably optimized away, actually)" because, you were correct about the fact that `NULL` doesn't cause problems when passed to `free()`. I didn't know that. But I'd stand for the rest of my comment.

Comment: @ShadowRanger-- Yes, that was the result of a too-hasty reading of the question. I initially thought that `input` was a character array; I realized that this was in error after my comment. I suggest using an array instead of manual allocation in my answer below.

Comment: I really appreciate your time guys. I'm a little new at this, so thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use `malloc()` here, it is not really necessary. You can `#define` a reasonable maximum line length, and declare a character array to hold the input. If you do this, you can remove the `free`s from your code.

You also have an issue with the way that you are using `fgets()`. The trailing `\n` is kept by `fgets()`, but your comparisons are ignoring this. Consequently, `input` is never equal to `"quit"`, and is certainly never `NULL`. I have included some code that removes the trailing newline after reading into `input`; the code also clears any remaining characters from the input stream, which is possible in the event that the user enters more than `MAXLINE - 1` characters. The test for text input is then simply `if (input[0])`. Alternatively, you could change your tests to take into account the extra '\n' character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXLINE  1000

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char input[MAXLINE];
    char *ch;                       // used to remove newline
    char c;                         // used to clear input stream

    // ensure one and only one command line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [name of document]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // open a new document for writing
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");

    // check for successful open
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not create %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    // get text from user and save to file
    while(true)
    {
        // get text from user
        printf("Enter a new line of text (or \"quit\"):\n");
        fgets(input, MAXLINE, stdin);

        //  remove trailing newline
        ch = input;
        while (*ch != '\n' &&  *ch != '\0') {
            ++ch;
        }
        if (*ch) {
            *ch = '\0';
        } else {         // remove any extra characters in input stream
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                continue;
        }

        // if user wants to quit
        if (strcmp(input, "quit") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        // if user wants to enter text
        else if (input[0])
        {
            fputs(input, fp);
            fputs("\n", fp);
            printf("CHA-CHING!\n\n");
        }
    }

    // close the file and end successfuly
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You never `malloc`-ed `input`, so yeah, `fgets` is dereferencing the `NULL` pointer as its buffer, and that's going to die. Either change `input` to a stack array (and remove the `free` for it) or actually call `malloc` to allocate memory so `input` isn't pointing to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Their are some problems in your code.

1. You have not allocated memory to input character pointer. Hence you can't store characters in it, hence you get segmentation fault.
2. Also you are **free**ing more than once, which is incorrect.

So, a code, with the above modification would be something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
      char* input = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);

      // ensure one and only one command line argument
      if (argc != 2)
      {
          printf("Usage: %s [name of document]\n", argv[0]);
          return 1;
      }

      // open a new document for writing
      FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");

      // check for successful open
      if(fp == NULL)
      {
          printf("Could not create %s\n", argv[1]);
          return 2;
      }

      // get text from user and save to file
      while(1)
      {
          // get text from user
          printf("Enter a new line of text (or \"quit\"):\n");
          fgets(input, 50, stdin);

          // if user wants to quit
          if (input != NULL && strcmp(input, "quit\n") == 0)
          {
              free(input);
              break;
          }
          // if user wants to enter text
          else if (input != NULL)
          {
              fputs(input, fp);
              fputs("\n", fp);
              printf("CHA-CHING!\n\n");
              // free(input);
          }
      }

      // close the file and end successfuly
      fclose(fp);
      return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps your problem. 
Cheers.

Comment: I'll more than grateful for the help, thanks for your time!

Comment: @IdrisSunmola, it would be better if you accept the answer which was helpful for you to solve your problem. This will save time of others when they look in this post.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it's because of the fgets function.

Yes: passing `NULL` pointer to `fgets` makes *no sense*, isn't allowed, and will cause a crash.

> I might need to malloc to solve the problem.

You need to pass a pointer to a *suitable* buffer for `fgets` to read input into. Whether that buffer is `malloc`ed, a local or a global array, is *irrelevant*.

TL;DR: *think* about what you are doing.